# How can I get language and keyword completion in omnifunc?

Tags: autocompletion, insert-mode, keyword, ins-completion

Let's say I'm editing this Python script:

```
something = 1
something_else = 2
```

My cursor is on the third line, in insert mode.

When `omnifunc` is unset, `<C-X><C-O>` displays an error:

```
E764: Option 'omnifunc' is not set
```

When `omnifunc` is set to `python3complete#Complete`, `<C-X><C-O>` lists the following three options:

- `something`
- `something_else`
- `__builtins__()`

Notably missing are said built-ins, like `print`, which I would expect to see.

When `omnifunc` is set to `syntaxcomplete#Complete`, `<C-X><C-O>` apparently lists every known Python built-in, including `print`. However, it doesn't include `something` or `something_else`.

What option (preferred) or plugin (if necessary) do I need to get a list including built-ins *and* local keywords?

Comment: With a Python LSP and `omnifunc` completing from it, you'll probably get the best options. However, for local words `C-n`/`C-p` might be better.